# for update in cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Why to use  FOR UPDATE in Cursor? the necessity of using it in cursor

Comment: what is advantage in doing so?

Answer (score 2):

If you define `FOR UPDATE` clause, it means that records in tbl_b from below example are locked from the point where you open cursor until the point where the transaction is commited or rollbacked.

```
CURSOR c
IS
  SELECT a
  FROM tbl_a
  FOR UPDATE OF tbl_b;
```

Then you can use `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause

```
UPDATE tbl_b
  SET set_clause
  WHERE CURRENT OF c;
```